# VBA (Excel ADODB ODBC) : Get list of stored procedures and tables from ANY database?

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, ado

I would like to be able to list stored procedures from an ODBC data connection using ADODB.

I have an ADO connection:

```
    Public DBConn As New ADODB.Connection 
    DBConn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
```

The user selects an ODBC datasource.

I then want to display a list of tables and stored procedures.

Can this be done generically without being specific to SQL server or Oracle (say)?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases have the "meta-view" collection called INFORMATION_SCHEMA (AKA SQL-92 standard).

If the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES view exists, then you you could list the stored procedures with it.

Oracle however, does not follow this standard, and it requires special attention, see:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/System-Tables-Views/listallstoredproceduresPROCEDUREFUNCTIONPACKAGEPACKAGEBODY.htm